# Music notation with valid use of B## and E##

Tags: key-signatures, accidentals

Can anyone show me a piece of repertoire that validly uses B## and E## notes?

I've had people tell me that of course they exist, but have never been able to give me an example; or they try to build a theoretical example using something like the key of A# major, rather than the much more simple Bb major.

This is just to prove to myself that a double-accidental is always a white note on the piano. :)

Comment: Why do you need a piece of music to validate double sharps? An augmented 5th above A# is E##, for example in an **A#+7** chord. Also, double sharps (which are not necessarily accidentals) are not always white keys. B## is enharmonic to C#, and E## is enharmonic to F#, neither of which are white keys.

Comment: It's the practicality of coming across them in sheet music - I stumbled over a lot of double sharps in a piece until I realised they were always the next white note up, then they were no problem. There are examples here of E## and Cbb which would seem to be quite rare, and then B## and Fbb would be rarer still. So the 'always a white note' thing might be a good enough heuristic.

Comment: A good heuristic for what purpose?  It would be far less confusing just to recognize that a double sharp is just two half steps higher, whether the note is black or white.

Answer (score 5):

Here is Scriabin's study op. 42, no. 5, bar 18, which includes an E-double-sharp...
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about pieces using B## or E##, but I can give an example of a piece of piano music using Cbb: Godowsky's paraphrase on Strauss's "Die Fledermaus". In the section below,

[image: Strauss/Godowsky Fledermaus Cbb example]

there is a Cbb in the left hand in the third bar, which is a double-accidental and which is a black note on the piano (enharmonic to Bb).

Answer (score 0):

**F♯♯maj13♯11 consists of the notes F♯♯-A♯♯-C♯♯-E♯♯-G♯♯-B♯♯-D♯♯**

*Enharmonic to Gmaj13♯11.*

Used in C♯♯ major as a IV chord.

How to theoretically use this absolute mess of a chord: If you started a piece in D♯ minor, then modulated to E♯ minor, then to E♯ major, then went to C♯♯ minor, then to C♯♯ major, you could theoretically use this chord as the IV. Basically, thorugh a bunch of modulations, it's possible to get there. Or you could be smart and just write augmented chords in sharp keys.